# How to paste/equalize specific range value in one sheets into another?

Tags: excel, vba

I have named `"FormEntry"` in `Range("E7,F11,H12,I8,E16")` in Sheet1. [image: Sheet1]

[image: Sheet2]

and picture above is `Sheet2`. 
Is that possible to copy Range `"FormEntry"` from `Sheet1` and paste/equalize into the same Range in `Sheets2` without other cells range in `Sheet2` being replaced?

I've tried this syntax but the values on Sheets2 are A's

```
Sub test()


 Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E7,F11,H12,I8,E16").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E7,F11,H12,I8,E16").Value



End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
For Each cell In Range("FormEntry")
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column).Value = cell.Value
Next
```